# Using a Date Picker to jump to a new page

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I'm using a simple HTML date picker:

```
<label for="start">Start month:
<input type="month" id="start" name="start" min="2017-01" max="2021-12" value="2020-05">
</label>
```

which works fine. I want to take the date chosen ("2017-11"), and jump to a particular spot on a page:

/reports/System_Uptime.html#2017-11

What JavaScript do I need to take the month/year selected, and append it to a link to load the appropriate page at the correct anchor?

This must have been done somewhere before, but I have found no examples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set up a `change` event handler that changes the `location.href` to the static value with the datepicker's `value` concatenated to it:

```js
 document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("change", function(){
  alert("Going to: /reports/System_Uptime.html#" + this.value);
  location.href = "/reports/System_Uptime.html#" + this.value;
});
```

```html
<label for="start">Start month:
<input type="month" id="start" name="start" min="2017-01" max="2021-12" value="2020-05">
</label>
```

Comment: This works great.... You're my new best friend.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @Fliteman  LOL. You're welcome. Don't forget to mark this as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an eventlistener to the `start` input and just `location.href` its value.

```
var start = document.querySelector("#start");

start.addEventListener("input",function(e){
   location.href = "#" + e.target.value;
});
```